# How do I schedule a task with Celery that runs on the last day of every month?

Tags: python-3.x, cron, celery

How do I schedule a task with Celery that runs on the last day of every month?

Regardless of a month having 28th, 29th, 30th or 31st dates.

Unable to find the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no easy way to accomplish this.  The best bet you'd have is to schedule the task to run every day and have the task itself check whether it was the last day of the month.